# How to create and XSD schema file from a Codefluent CFP file?

Tags: xsd, codefluent, altova

I'm working on a project which uses Codefluent entities to define the application's schema and produce and SQL database, class libraries, web pages, and winforms.  Also used are the Altova XmlSpy products.

I am trying to figure out how I can extract from the Codefluent model an XSD schema representation of the Codefluent model so that it could be used with Altova's XmlStyleVision.

In Softfluent's documentation, https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/CF_Tools_Builder.html, there is a compile option "/ExtractSchema" but that create 5000 lines of attributes and enumerations and contains nothing relating to the data model.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/ExtractSchema` extracts the xsd for creating CodeFluent Entities models. For instance, this allows you to get auto-completion in Visual Studio. This schema is not related to your model, and is not what you want.

The easiest way to generate a schema for you model is to create a template and add the Template Producer to your model. First, create a folder and add a file named `[Template]schema.xsd` (must be prefixed by [Template]). I don't know what Altova's XmlStyleVision needs, but the following template should be a good start.

```
[%@ namespace name="CodeFluent.Model"%]
[%@ namespace name="CodeFluent.Model.Persistence"%]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
[%foreach (Entity e in Producer.Project.Entities)
{%]
    <xs:element name="[%= e.Name %]">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
            [%foreach (Property p in e.Properties) { %]      
                <xs:element name="[%= p.Name %]" type="xs:string" />
            [% } %]                    
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
[% } %]
</xs:schema>
```

Finally, add the template producer to your model: https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/TemplateProducers_TemplateProducer.html

Now, the xsd file will be generated when you build the model.